# Logistic regression: Absolute values for P

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, outliers, residuals

I am stuck with a problem (actually two problems).

I have a dataset of about 150 cases and 30 or so dichotonous (yes/no) parameters. I selected 6 parameters (after literature study and crosstabs) for which I want to do a logistic regression analysis.

Problem 1
1 of the independent variables if true, has a 100% effect on the outcome. So if this variable is 1 (true), then the dependent variable is always also 1 (true). If the independent variable is false, then the dependent variable is about 50/50 true/false.

Using these 5 variables in a logistic regression gives me this:

```
Variables in the Equation                           
                        B       S.E.        Wald    df  Sig.    Exp(B)
Step 1a variable_1      4,030   ,990        16,567  1   ,000    56,273
        variable_2      3,097   ,858        13,030  1   ,000    22,133
        variable_3      3,565   1,394       6,538   1   ,011    35,324
        variable_4      3,010   1,135       7,036   1   ,008    20,290
        variable_5      21,485  4184,125    ,000    1   ,996    2142215354,293
        Constant        -3,278  ,742        19,509  1   ,000    ,038
a Variable(s) entered on step 1: Foreseeability_foreseeability_1n2, D_Norm_Violation, D_Competence_1, D_Context_1, Bad_faith.
```

How should I interpret these results? I can understand the B value for variable 5:
if

```
P(x)=1/(1-exp(-logit(x))), with logit(x)=b0+b1*x1+..+bn*xn,
```

then for P(x) to be 1, exp(-logit) needs to be 0, so logit needs to approximate infinity. SPSS only does 20 interations, so finds 21.485 "infinite" enough. I do not understand why (according to literature) this variable has no value to the model because of the high Sig.

My guess was to remove all cases where variable_5=1 (sort of making a flowchart model) and doing the logistic regression on the other 4 variables. Is this the right course? What do the numbers in above table tell me about my model?

Anyway, using the 4 variables, we come to my second problem.
The logistic regression for the 4 variables turns out fine:

```
Variables in the Equation                           
                    B       S.E.    Wald    df  Sig.    Exp(B)
Step 1a variable_1  4,713   ,797    34,970  1   ,000    111,399
        variable_2  3,101   ,668    21,585  1   ,000    22,228
        variable_3  1,989   1,384   2,065   1   ,151    7,308
        variable_4  2,575   ,993    6,721   1   ,010    13,130
        Constant    -2,566  ,543    22,337  1   ,000    ,077
a Variable(s) entered on step 1: Foreseeability_foreseeability_1n2, D_Norm_Violation, D_Competence_1, D_Context_1.
```

However, when looking at the residuals, I have 1 outlier. This case, which is a actually a data error, has 0's for all independent variables, yes the dependent variable is 1. Ok, great, data error, thank you for pointing it out, dear SPSS, let's remove the case and rerun the logistic regression. The result is that for all values for B (including the contant) I get values of over 30, and for all B, the Sig is in the 0.99's.

I understand all the high B values:
If, in all cases where all 4 independent variables are 0, and the dependent variable is also 0, for that to be the outcome P(x) needs to be 0. For P(x) to be 0, logit(x) needs to approximate -∞ (a very large negative number). Because all x are 0, only b0 (the constant) can contribute to logit approaching -∞. Because the number of iterations SPSS can do is limited, SPSS finds a large negative number (-30, or -40) is a close enough approximation. P(0) with b0 ≈ -30 is 4x10-18 (very, very small). In this case, other values of bn need to be of the same magnitude as b0 to “compete” in cases where some or all independent variables are not 0. This will result in the outcome of P(x) either being 0 (in case all xn are 0), or 1 in case 2 or more xn are 1, or, in case of only one xn being 1, inaccurate results for P(x).

So my understanding is, that logistic regression cannot cope with something happening with either 100% change of it happening (problem 1) or 0% chance of it happening (problem 1).

How should I proceed?
In problem 1, should I indeed use a flowchart (if variable_5 is true, then outcome is true, if variable_5 is not true, then continue to model with 4 variables)
In problem 2, should I not delete the outlier (data error), so my model seems to have a nice outcome? If so, how do I explain that? If not, what then?